# How do I convert strings between uppercase and lowercase in Java?

Tags: java, string

What is the method for converting strings in Java between upper and lower case?

Comment: develop the habit of reading the API documentation (Javadocs) that way you will get first hand information.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[String#toLowerCase](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29) and [String#toUpperCase](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29) are the methods you need.

Comment: Although 'toUpperCase' will give the opposite effect, I'll still give you +1 :-)

Comment: Fixed (including linking to Java6 docs - does anyone even still use 1.4?) and upvoted.

Comment: @Fortega - the OP said "converting between" not "converting from / to".  Converting between implies converting in both directions.

Answer (score 23):

There are methods in the String class; `toUppercase()` and `toLowerCase()`.

i.e.

```
String input = "Cricket!";
String upper = input.toUpperCase(); //stores "CRICKET!"
String lower = input.toLowerCase(); //stores "cricket!"
```

This will clarify your doubt

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There are methods on the String itself for this.

Note that the result depends on the Locale the JVM is using. Beware, locales is an art in itself.

Comment: Yup. I recently discovered that the size of string is not always the same as the size of string.toUpperCase()

Comment: Yes but only in those weird languages with umlauts and Eszett and names like Thorbjørn :-)

Comment: you mean like weird languages like every other language on the planet?

Comment: Actually we use ISØ-Låtin-1 here in Sĉändïñävïä so it could be a LØT WØRSË :)

Answer (score 2):

[String#toLowerCase](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all characters are alphabetic, you can do this:

From lowercase to uppercase:

```
// Uppercase letters. 
class UpperCase {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    char ch;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
      ch = (char) ('a' + i);
      System.out.print(ch); 

      // This statement turns off the 6th bit.   
      ch = (char) ((int) ch & 65503); // ch is now uppercase
      System.out.print(ch + " ");  
    } 
  } 
}
```

From uppercase to lowercase:

```
// Lowercase letters. 
class LowerCase {  
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    char ch;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) { 
      ch = (char) ('A' + i);
      System.out.print(ch);
      ch = (char) ((int) ch | 32); // ch is now uppercase
      System.out.print(ch + " ");  
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coverting the first letter of word capital

input:

hello
world

```
String A = hello;
String B = world;
System.out.println(A.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+A.substring(1) + " " + B.toUpperCase().charAt(0)+B.substring(1));
```

Output:

Hello World