# String river = "This is a Test"; to be lowercase using Eclipse.exe

Tags: java, eclipse, string, methods, lowercase

How can I get 
String river = "This is a Test";
to become lowercase using Eclipse? I have already tried multiple ways using bigRiver but it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert strings between uppercase and lowercase in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951856/how-do-i-convert-strings-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `river.toLowercase()`? or better yet `river.toLowercase(Locale.English)`;

Answer (score 0):

`String` is immutable in Java, so you must assign the reference for the `river` to be modified.

```
String river = "This is a Test";
System.out.printf("Before: %s%n", river);
river = river.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.printf("After: %s%n", river);
```

Outputs

```
Before: This is a Test
After: this is a test
```