# How can I change only first character case to opposite of every word in line?

Tags: java

Words can be separated by one or several spaces
I don't understand how to arrange a check for lower or upper case only for first character in word
How can I change only first character case to opposite of every word in line

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> A = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            A.add(s.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example (Input string and output string)? The question is not clear

Comment: input: Sss Kkk ppp

Comment: output: sss kkk Ppp

Comment: Take a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951856/how-do-i-convert-strings-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can always check `str.charAt(0)` with `Character.isUpperCase()`/`Character.isLowerCase()`, and then change case with `Character.toUpperCase()`/`Character.toLowerCase()` and then append the rest of string(with `substring()`.

I think you don't need to add the line before changing it; you should do it afterwards maybe?

BTW a small rewording helps to make yourself clearer. I guess you want to add some commas between the words, and before the code you can add "This is what I have got now: ..."