# Produce lowercase character instead of uppercase in Java

Tags: java, string, character, lowercase

The output is fine but the output is in Uppercase letter, I want the output to be lowercase character, what should I do?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q2 {
      
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a[]=new int[26];
            Scanner sc =  new Scanner (System.in);
            String str=sc.nextLine();
            for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++) {
                if(str.charAt(i)>=65 && str.charAt(i)<=90) {
                    a[str.charAt(i)-65]++;
                }
                else if(str.charAt(i)>=97 && str.charAt(i)<=122) {
                    a[str.charAt(i)-97]++;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0;i<26;i++) {
                if(a[i]>0) {
                    System.out.print(" "+(char )(i+65)+ "(" + a[i]+")");
                }
                
            }
                    
        }       

}
```

Comment: You can use char literals instead of int literals, e.g. `'A'` instead of `65`, `'a'` instead of `97`. That would make it easier to see what "sum" you are actually doing.

Comment: Also, define a variable `char c = str.charAt(i);`, then you don't need to keep repeating `str.charAt(i)`, which would make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

`'A'` is 65. `'a'` is 97. Use 97 instead of 65 in your final loop.

Alternatively use `'a'` directly instead of the number. This makes it more obvious what you're doing in that code.

Comment: Nit: `'@'` is 64; `'A'` is 65.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more straightforward to convert the entire string to lower case to avoid checking for upper case letters.

Also, as suggested earlier using character literals as `a` instead of 97 would make the code more readable.

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a[] = new int[26];

String str = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        a[c - 'a']++;
    }
}
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    int i = c - 'a';
    if (a[i] > 0) {
        System.out.print(" "+ c + "(" + a[i] + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out this post with a accepted answer [How do I convert strings between uppercase and lowercase in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951856/how-do-i-convert-strings-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-in-java)

You could probably do something like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q2 {
      
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a[]=new int[26];
            Scanner sc =  new Scanner (System.in);
            String str=sc.nextLine();
            String lowerCaseInput = str.toLowerCase();
            System.out.print(lowerCaseInput);
        }
}
```